# Incompatibility using Java Generics, Interfaces and Inheritance

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, interface

I have a serious issue with my code; I'm using Generics, Interfaces and classes implementing such interfaces; to sum up:

**ConfigurationListener.java**

```
public interface ConfigurationListener<T extends Configuration> {
    public void configurationChange(ConfigurationProperty<?> [] changes, T configuration);
}
```

**Configuration.java**

```
public class Configuration {
    ...
    protected HashSet<ConfigurationListener<? super Configuration>> listeners;
    ...
    public void applyTo(ConfigurationListener<? super Configuration> listener) {
        if (listeners.add(listener)) {
            ...
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

**XMLConfiguration.java**

```
public class XMLConfiguration extends Configuration {
    ...
    @Override
    public void applyTo(ConfigurationListener<? super Configuration> listener) {
        tryLoad(); // Try to load the content of the XML file
        super.applyTo(listener);
    }
    ...
}
```

When I was testing, I found the following problem, and I really don't understand why:

**t3b.java**

```
public class t3b {
    public static class Human implements ConfigurationListener<XMLConfiguration> {
        @Override
        public void configurationChange(ConfigurationProperty<?>[] changes, XMLConfiguration configuration) {
            ...
        }
    }
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        XMLConfiguration conf = new XMLConfiguration("xmlconf.xml", "sectn", new ConfigurationProperty<?> [] {
            new ConfigurationProperty<Integer>("age", 23),
            new ConfigurationProperty<String>("name", "Juan")
        });
        conf.applyTo(new Human());
    }
}
```

The line

```
conf.applyTo(new Human());
```

breaks it all; Eclipse SDK gives me the following error:

> The method applyTo(ConfigurationListener) in
>   the type XMLConfiguration is not applicable for the arguments
>   (t3b.Human)

But **t3b.Human** implements **ConfigurationListener** using a child of **Configuration**!! That's what I don't understand.

I know that the logic of my code could be simpler, but I'd like to know why is it failing.

I don't think that posting posting the code of **ConfigurationProperty.java** matters at all, but if it helps, tell me and I'll post it.

Thanks!

Comment: You're using `? super Configuration`, not `? extends Configuration`.

Comment: I also have a vague hunch that this design isn't sound / typesafe.

Comment: Nope, it indeed is not. You can't have a `ConfigurationListener` that doesn't accept every subtype of `Configuration`, because `listeners` can store listeners for any subtype. So when it fires `configurationChange()`, there's no way to tell which listener can accept that change.

Comment: But what would be the difference between super and extends in this case?

Comment: As far as I know, super is "more strict" than extends, right? But I don't see how that would change anything.

Comment: Why would it be "more strict"? `? super Configuration` means "any type that is a **supertype** of `Configuration`". Meaning "**not** types that are **subtypes** of `Configuration`". Besides, as I said, I doubt juggling keywords will help here, your whole design is problematic. Why does `XMLConfiguration` accept listeners for *every* type of `Configuration`, not just `XMLConfiguration` specifically? (It doesn't help that a "configuration" is the same thing as a "collection of listeners". It makes it hard to talk about the different concerns.)

Comment: Now I've read more about wildcards and Generics in general, and I totally agree to your comment, however, I still need to keep that design logic; I'll have to adapt it somehow.

Comment: You have two choices. Either have `ConfigurationListener` accept any type of `Configuration`, and maybe reject events by using `instanceof` at runtime. Or get rid of the wildcards, with something like `class Configuration<TConfiguration extends Configuration>`, `class XMLConfiguration extends Configuration<XMLConfiguration>` where `Configuration` only fires events for the subtype it actually is. (This might require an unsafe cast or a type check using a type token somewhere too.)

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking, but I it's too verbose, I don't find it really practical; I'll go with creating a `ConfigurationListener` for each `Configuration`, and, instead of making `XMLConfiguration` to extend `Configuration`, I'll create a common super class for both.

Comment: Well, whatever works for you. What I suggested were the two ways to make your existing design sound. If a more thorough revision is better in your case, then do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your method requires `ConfigurationListener<? super Configuration>` (any type that is a super type of `Configuration`, or `Configuration` itself) and `ConfigurationListener` requires `T extends Configuration` (any type that is a sub type of `Configuration`, or `Configuration` itself). The only `T` that would satisfy both of those conditions is `Configuration`, but `Human implements ConfigurationListener<XMLConfiguration>`, so it is ineligible.

Comment: I changed it, but it now gives me another error; whenever I try to call `configurationChange` it says the parameter types are not compatible.

Comment: I think I know why already; It doesn't know whether I'm sending the correct child of `Configuration`. I'll have to change the design.